Find the address of a virtual method from base class

CPU : Mac M (AArch64)
Complier : XCode (Clang)

We have the following classes from UE5
class IRHIComputeContext {}

class IRHICommandContext : public IRHIComputeContext
{
    // pure virtual method
    virtual void RHICopyTexture(FRHITexture* SourceTexture, FRHITexture* DestTexture, const FRHICopyTextureInfo& CopyInfo) = 0;
}

class FMetalRHICommandContext : public IRHICommandContext
{
    // overridden final virtual method
    virtual void RHICopyTexture(FRHITexture* SourceTextureRHI, FRHITexture* DestTextureRHI, const FRHICopyTextureInfo& CopyInfo) final override;
}

class FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext : public FMetalRHICommandContext
{
}


As the above code shows, the inheritance goes in this way:
FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext <-- FMetalRHICommandContext <-- IRHICommandContext <-- IRHIComputeContext

There is a RHICopyTexture method defined in IRHICommandContext and overridden in FMetalRHICommandContext.
Now I have a FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext* pointer, I want to retrieve the address of RHICopyTexture for hooking.
    FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext* Context = StaticCast<FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext*>(GDynamicRHI->RHIGetDefaultContext());
    check(Context);
    FMetalDeviceContext& MetalDeviceContext = Context->GetInternalContext();
    
    void** const pCastedToHeader = reinterpret_cast<void**>(Context);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(*Context) / sizeof(void*); i++)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Pointer[%04zu] = 0x%016X"), i, pCastedToHeader[i]);
    }
    
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("&IRHICommandContext::RHICopyTexture = %d"), &IRHICommandContext::RHICopyTexture);
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("&FMetalRHICommandContext::RHICopyTexture = %d"), &FMetalRHICommandContext::RHICopyTexture);
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("&FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext::RHICopyTexture = %d"), &FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext::RHICopyTexture);

&IRHICommandContext::RHICopyTexture = 720
&FMetalRHICommandContext::RHICopyTexture = 720
&FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext::RHICopyTexture = 720

The RHICopyTexture offset is 720(0x2D0), this is the same as I retrieve from get_cxx_member_func_ptr method below. But Pointer[720] is zero and it is out of the valid memory range of sizeof(*Context) which is only 512.
As I understand, each class type gets its own standalone vtable containing the slots pointing to methods from base table. My code works for other virtual methods defined in current class but not for the inherited one here. How can I find the real address of RHICopyTexture ?
// https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/cppabi64/cppabi64.rst#representation-of-pointer-to-member-function
template<typename Func>
inline void* get_cxx_member_func_ptr(void* BaseAddress, Func f) {
    // a pointer to member function is a pair of words <ptr, adj>
    verify(sizeof(f) == 16);
    union {
        Func Fcn;
        struct {
          // The generic C++ ABI [GCPPABI] specifies that the least significant bit of ptr discriminates between
          // (0) the address of a non-virtual member function and
          // (1) the offset in the class’s virtual table of the address of a virtual function.
          // However, this encoding cannot work for the AArch64 instruction set where the architecture reserves all bits of code addresses.
          // This ABI specifies that adj contains twice the this adjustment, plus 1 if the member function is virtual.
          // The least significant bit of adj then makes exactly the same discrimination as the least significant bit of ptr does for Itanium.
          // A pointer to the member function to call.  If the member function is
          // virtual, this will be a thunk that forwards to the appropriate vftable
          // slot.
          void *FunctionPointerOrVirtualThunk;
          int IsVirtual;
        };
    };
    Fcn = f;
    if (!IsVirtual){
        return FunctionPointerOrVirtualThunk;
    }
    else {
        uint64_t ThunkIndex = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(FunctionPointerOrVirtualThunk);
        void*** VTable = reinterpret_cast<void***>(BaseAddress);
        return *(VTable[ThunkIndex]);
    }
}

UPDATE:
There are two virtual tables.

_ZTV23FMetalRHICommandContext for class FMetalRHICommandContext which contains the definition of RHICopyTexture
_ZTV32FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext for the derived class FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext

The pointer of FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext* refers to the vptr address.  The vptr address is 16bytes(0x10) bigger to its vtable address _ZTV32FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext.
The problem is that,  the slot in _ZTV32FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext is zero for the inherited virtual method RHICopyTexture.
But it does exist in the base class's vtable _ZTV23FMetalRHICommandContext.

Get memory address of member function? and How to print member function address in C++

Non-virtual member function is simple because absolute address is in pointer directly.  While virtual member function's address is not there.

Yes, as the above linked answer also points that out.

it can be done because vtable is the same for a given class.  I have done this for virtual method in other classes.  The problem here is about inheritance.  I checked C++ ABI and don't understand how  Clang(XCode) compiles the code.

You're aware of godbolt, right?

@user12002570 wow, I was looking for IDA running on Mac ARM CPU to disassemble the binaries.  Really didn't know there is an online version. thanks a lot

You're welcome. It(godbolt) is an excellent(/very useful) tool/site etc.

Note that use of a vtable is an implementation detail and not mandated by the standard. A compiler is free to use a different implementation and you cannot rely on it.

Here is code to retrieve member function pointer in ARM64(Clang)

template<typename Func>
inline void* get_cxx_member_func_ptr(const gpointer Instance, Func f) {
    // a pointer to member function is a pair of words <ptr, adj>
    verify(sizeof(f) == 16);
    union {
        Func Fcn;
        struct {
          // A pointer to the member function to call.  If the member function is
          // virtual, this will be a thunk that forwards to the appropriate vftable
          // slot.
          void *FunctionPointerOrVirtualThunk;
          int IsVirtual;
        };
    };
    Fcn = f;
    if (!IsVirtual){
        return FunctionPointerOrVirtualThunk;
    }
    else {
        void** VPtr = *(reinterpret_cast<void***>(Instance));
        uint64_t ThunkIndex = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(FunctionPointerOrVirtualThunk);
        
        // vtable starts with offset_to_top and RTTI
        // hence vptr pointer is 16bytes behind vtable. e.g.
        // VTable = 0x0000000324E02708
        // VPtr   = 0x0000000324E02718
        // More details: https://taylorbowland.com/posts/virtual-tables/
        
        return VPtr[ThunkIndex/sizeof(void*) - 2];
    }
}

If you dislike the dirty approach above replying on complier's implementation, perhaps you can locate the vtable address by exported symbol
extern "C" {
    #include "frida-gum.h"
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
}


static gboolean find_export_in_module(const GumModuleDetails * details, gpointer user_data)
{
    GumExportDetails* target = (GumExportDetails*)user_data;
    
    if (target) {
        target->address = gum_module_find_export_by_name( details->name, target->name);
    }
    
    return target->address == 0;
}


static gpointer find_vtable_address(const char* export_name) {
    gum_init_embedded();
    
    GumExportDetails target;
    target.name = export_name;
    target.address = GPOINTER_TO_SIZE(nullptr);
    target.type = GUM_EXPORT_VARIABLE;
    gum_process_enumerate_modules(find_export_in_module, &target);
    
    return GSIZE_TO_POINTER(target.address);
}


void** VTable = reinterpret_cast<void**>(find_vtable_address("_ZTV32FMetalRHIImmediateCommandContext"));

